# Expected value of a recursive random function

Tags: probability, recursion, random

```
   function foo(n)  
     if n = 1 then  
        return randint(INT_MAX)
     else  
        return randint(foo(n-1))
     end if  
   end function
```

The idea is that the function recursively decides the next maximum value for an random integer.

If `foo` is initially called with `m` as the parameter, what is the expected value of the output? Also is it possible to plot a rough distribution function?

BTW, `randint(n)`  returns a uniformly distributed random integer in the range 0 to `n`.

Few examples for m = 10 and INT_MAX = 2^31-1:

````
0: 1773222062
1: 302320327
2: 217321806
3: 167172143
4: 16407259
5: 11236721
6: 10246171
7: 7399283
8: 2797307
9: 450964
10: 65659

0: 758108310 
1: 496236452 
2: 339520617 
3: 254288094 
4: 109227996 
5: 44669101  
6: 41496117  
7: 18575039  
8: 826387    
9: 207751    
10: 170187   
```
````

Comment: Well, unless, I am misreading, eventually you just get randint(m) which has expected value $\frac m2$.

Comment: It goes more like randint(randint(randint(...randint(INT_MAX)))) m times. Which means that the maximum value for the random function changes each iteration.

Comment: Right, I misread.

Comment: If $M$ is a positive real random variable and $X\sim\text{Unif}(0, M)$, meaning the conditional probability distribution of $X$ given $M$ is $\text{Unif}(0, M)$, then we should have $E(X)=\frac{E(M)}2$. I don't have time to work out the details right now, but from this it would follow that the the expected value of `foo(n)` is about $\frac {\text{INT_MAX}} {2^{n-1}}$, give or take some accounting for the discrete nature of `randint`.

Comment: Not sure I follow your example.  I thought $m$ was INT_MAX.    What is $m$?

Comment: `m` is the number of times randint is called

Comment: Where in the code is $m$ used?  Perhaps (probably?) I am still misreading, but I thought the only parameters in the code were $n$ and MAX_INT.

Comment: I'm calling the function as `foo(m)`

Comment: So, $n=m$ then?  Ok, in that case I believe my posted solution applies.  I note that the answer it yields coincides with the answer proposed by @JackM

Comment: I ran the above code with INT_MAX = 2^31-1 and m = 2 100000 times in python. I'm  getting a mean of about 269216906.8261183. Which is about 75% off

Comment: @PrateekDhanuka Is the code you ran equivalent to that posted in the question? Because I notice in your results you included the case $n=0$, but the code you posted has a base case of $n=1$.

Comment: I edited the code bbefore running it. Here's the code: ```import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rand(count):
 if count == 1:
  number = np.random.randint(2**31-1)
 else:
  number = rand(count-1)
 return np.random.randint(number)
 
values = []
count = 2
for i in range(1,100000):
 values.append(rand(count))

print(f'Average: {np.mean(values)}')

plt.hist(values)
plt.show()
``` Sorry I am unable to properly format it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mu = $ MAX_INT.  Let $E_n[\mu]$ be the desired expected value of foo$(n)$.  We have $E_1[\mu]=\frac {\mu}2$ and $E_n[0]=0$

For a general $n$ we have $E_n[\mu]=\frac 1{\mu+1} \sum_{i=0}^{\mu} E_{n-1}[i]$

It is a simple matter to confirm that $$E_n[\mu]=\frac {\mu
}{2^{n}}$$ satisfies this recursion and the initial conditions, so we are done.

Comment: Actually, we must have made the same mistake because in fact the answer is $\frac\mu{2^n}$.

Comment: @JackM  Yes...that's odd.  I didn't see your comment as I was writing this, but I think I had run through an argument substantially similar to what you wrote.  Of course we need $2^n$ to match the initial condition at $n=1$.  I will edit accordingly.